# Defining type to history.push() which has been passed as a payload to the saga using typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have used `{ useHistory } from react-router-dom` in the react component. And on button click am try to pass the history instance as a payload to the saga through action.ts

component.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import {recievingHistoryAsPayload } from 'store/actions';


const Component: React.FC = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const sendHistoryObj = () => {
   dispatch(recievingHistoryAsPayload({ payload: history }));
 };
 return (
  <Button
      onClick={sendHistoryObj}
  />
 );
};

export default Component;
```

action.ts

```
export const recievingHistoryAsPayload = createAction(
 Types.RECEIVING_HISTORY_AS_PAYLOAD,
 (data) => data
);
```

saga.ts

```
export function* recievingHistoryAsPayloadSaga(action: any): Generator {
  yield call(action?.payload?.push, '/');
}
```

in saga.ts, for action payload eslint is throwing a warring with message `Argument 'action' should be typed with a non-any type.`

What should be type defined for action in saga.ts

Comment: Is `createAction` from `@reduxjs/toolkit`?

Comment: It should be of the same type as your `Types.RECEIVING_HISTORY_AS_PAYLOAD`

Comment: Yes its createAction from @reduxjs/toolkit